# How can I spawn a long running python process from a python script served by Apache running on ubuntu?

Tags: python, apache, process, daemon, spawn

Everything I've found so far is good ONLY IF if it's not being used in a web environment.

I have a simple python 'admin tool' web app running in Apache, and I'm using the simple configuration in the vhost :

`AddHandler cgi-script .py.`

There's no need for high performance, there's no python framework. Users select certain criteria which is sent via a GET request to the server & a python script then gets called by apache and the report is compiled. Problem is that the report complexity is growing, and the length of time it takes to compile this report can be > 20 minutes so I want to spawn a new totally independent process to generate the report asynchronously, allowing the server to return quickly to the client.

My issue is that I've tried absolutely everything I can find to be able to do this, and everything fails in the same way; when I spawn a new process the parent script will not return to the client until the new process has completed.

All of these do exactly the same - they start a new process BUT the main script waits for the child process to finish before returning to the client. I want the main script to return straight back to the client, and leave the newly spawned process running to compile the report.

```
os.system("""
cd /the_directory
python -m web.wait &
""")
```

```
command = ['python', '/the_directory/wait.py &']
Popen(command, shell=True, start_new_session=True)
```

```
L = ['python', '/the_directory/wait.py']
os.spawnvp(os.P_NOWAIT, 'python', L)
```

```
L = ['test.sh']
os.spawnvpe(os.P_NOWAIT, '/the_directory/test.sh', L, os.environ)


where test.sh contains: 

#!/bin/sh
/the_directory/wait.py &
```

```
jobs = []
for i in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=wait.dostuff, )
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
```

I want the simplest possible solution to this - it's an admin tool maintained only by me for a very few users.

If there's really no way to accomplish this then I guess I will have to use cron running once a minute and use a simple queue, maybe with redis or something, but this is not ideal.

I used to do this kind of thing relatively easily in php, I can't believe it's not possible in python.

Comment: Alternatively from the apache python script I *could* make an Ajax call to a php script which executes a shell script that starts the python report generator - but who in their right mind would want to do that ?!?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Popen` with `shell=False`

example:

```
Popen(["bash", "test.sh"], shell=False)
```

Comment: Hi Dusan this behaves exactly the same as the other things I tried. The main script served by Apache waits until the new long-running py process finishes and only then does it flush to the browser.
It feels like there's something fundamental that needs to change and then ALL the usual techniques will work. I just haven't found what it is yet.